# Flex container item not honouring height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Needing some help with CSS flexbox today. I believe I've configured flexbox right, I want each list item to stack, and then each div in the `li` to perform a `space-between` and have the content centered vertically in each div. This is to serve in an auto-complete.. How it is actually displaying though is: (not seeming to honour a height setting)

[image]

I have created a code snippet, code simplified from angular.io removed for sake of example. The isolated code snippet appears to work fine! Can you guys see anything else that could be causing an issue?

```css
ul.search-result {
  margin-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 0;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  z-index: 99;
  display: none;
  //width: 355px;
  //height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
    }
    
    li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;//60px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #E9EDEF;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: solid 1px red;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="search-result" style="width:500px;max-height:500px;">
    <li>
      <div class="icon">
        image
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <div class="name">name</div>
        <div class="location">location</div>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
        status
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="icon">
        image
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <div class="name">name</div>
        <div class="location">location</div>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
        status
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="icon">
        image
      </div>
      <div class="title">
        <div class="name">name</div>
        <div class="location">location</div>
      </div>
      <div class="status">
        status
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, further investigation reveals I'm actually setting maxHeight dynamically depending on the browser's height (mobile device) and this is causing it to play up. Still no solution yet though.

Comment: Have you tried not using flex?
please, create a jsfiddle project, which represents the issue, that makes it easier to answer.

Comment: add `flex-shrink:0` to your element and see

Comment: In the end, I simply re-jigged all my CSS and html to follow this approach from scratch and it worked. Thanks for the trouble. http://jsfiddle.net/ga6g4/2/

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I simply re-jigged all my CSS and html to follow this approach I mentioned in my final comment on the question.

Thanks for the trouble.

Comment: Consider posting a complete answer. A self-contained answer is more useful (e.g., it's simpler to share).